# com.itextpdf.text which itext jar last version was included?

Tags: itext, itext7

what is the jar version com.itextpdf.text package was included ?
I was using this code below maven code updating package version 7.0.0 
Showing errors while building the application and cloud not generate the jar file in the maven repository location ,I thought  will able to get the external jar file use it.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
<version>7.0.0</version>
```

Answer (score 1):

iText was rewritten from scratch a couple of years ago. During this operation, the package names were changed so that there wouldn't be any clashes if people used both versions next to each other.

The package name `com.itextpdf.text` was used with the iText 5 series. All iText 5 versions are being phased out. If you start a new project, you should start with iText 7, not iText 5.

If you are working on an existing project, then there are two options:

- Either you are distributing iText in an open source context (using the AGPL license); in that case, please show us where you have published the full source code of your project (making your own code open source is required if you're using iText for free under the AGPL).
- Or you are distributing iText in a closed source context. In that case, you should be a paying customer (if not, you are in violation with the AGPL). As a paying customer, you have the right to updates of iText 5 with bug fixes. We won't add new functionality to iText 5, but we make *maintenance releases* at the request of our paying customers.

Summarized: either use iText 7 (but then don't use the `com.itextpdf.text` packages); or use iText 5 (5.5.13 was the latest maintenance release), but only if you have to support legacy software. In both cases, make sure that you purchased a commercial license if you are working in a closed source context.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: read *and understand* Bruno's answer.

**iText 7**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This is a pom-only dependency that pulls in all iText modules, even the ones you don't need. See https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java for detailed installation instructions (so you only pull in the dependencies you really need) and a compatibility matrix.

---

**iText 5**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Information valid as of 17 April 2018. In a few days this information will already will be obsolete, when iText 7.1.2 comes out.

Comment: i am up grading from  5.5.9 to 7.0 latest version the package (com.itextpdf.text) but i could not find the some classes like com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException, com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64;

Comment: we are existing paid customers only, we are trying to upgrade latest version from 5.5.9,Could you please help me easy way to migrate the latest version.

Comment: If you are an existing customer with a support contract, then you do not have to use Stack Overflow and you can contact iText Software directly. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support